# Export Neo4j to GraphML with node/edge labels?

Tags: neo4j, gephi, graphml

Has anyone been able to export GraphML, readable by Gephi or yEd, which properly displays labels in Gephi/yEd?

I'm using the latest Neo4j community and APOC; I can export GraphML from APOC just fine, and import into Gephi/yEd, but there doesn't seem to be a way to load the attributes/key/data elements, so that useful labels can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the top of the graphml-file, along with the other keys.

```
<key id="labels" for="node" attr.name="labels"/>
```

You can then copy the "labels" property to the Label column in Gephi.

Answer (score 0):

For who is using Neo4j / APOC 4.x.x pay attention to add `{readLabels: true}` to your CALL or the nodes will appear just as grey dots.

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;
CALL apoc.import.graphml("file:///mypgraph.graphml", {readLabels: true});
MATCH (n) RETURN n;
```

Reference:

- https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/graphml/